# FTP to SQL DB on Microsoft Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssis, ftp

I have to update the question here. So, I have a clearer picture on how to push live data into SQL DB on Azure, although I think SSIS can do so at much faster rate but I'm sticking with the Azure solution. There are several options here to consider, but I'm going with the solution below:

[image]

But now, I have an issue to delete the blob inside the container. I don't know how to do so. I have tried to used the solutions provided in this forum as well as MSDN forum.. but came to no avail. So if any of you out there know how to access a blob/storage account in powershell, please contribute to this thread.
If this thread helps, do vote.

Regards,
Dein

Comment: Tough question....there are cost considerations for Azure depending on how much and how often you need data to move; however, my experience with SSIS and SFTP has resulted in a need to revisit this type of solution once servers were upgraded as: "The FTP Task in SSIS does not support SFTP (Secured FTP)" Really the only way to accomplish this is via 3rd party installation like WinScp which will provide your SSIS with available methods to script into tasks.

Comment: To be honest I'm not an expert on SSIS and by the looks of the whole process, I think it is a really complicated yet powerful system. And being a commoners, I don't think I want to use SSIS. Thanks mate for your suggestions

Comment: Logic App would be probably cheaper than an ADF. Usig ADF I am almost sure you can directly pish to Azure SQL - no need for intermediate blob storage. Also ADF seems like an overkill for that task. For SSIS you would need a licensed SQL server - much more expensive then just a Logic App.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @astaykov, the logic app works well. Hence, if you need a cheaper yet convenient way to transfer live data from your FTP server into a SQL DB or BLOB storage, you may use Azure Logic App. Please refer to the below links for tutorial.

**FTP data into BLOB**
http://mythoughtlab.azurewebsites.net/azure/using-logic-apps-to-transfer-files-from-ftp-into-azure-blob-storage/

**FTP data into SQL DB**
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-sqlazure#insert-row

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. The above solution on pumping the data from FTP to SQL DB via Logic App seems to be an invalid option. I have serious trouble inserting new data (of .csv) from the FTP into a new row of a table in the DB. The APIs aren't just that user friendly. Hence, if any of you out there knows a better way to transport data from a FTP folder into SQL DB tables that is structured by month and year, please contribute your solutions here. Thank you